# replace only sub string which has class highlight javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, innerhtml

I have the following code:

```js
document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML = document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML.replace(rxp, "abc");
```

```html
<div id="rep"> asd 123 asd <span class="light">123</span> asd 123 asd <span class="light">123</span> </div>
```

Here, `rxp` is a regular expression which matches the numbers.
Problem is that I want to replace only those `123` that are not enclosed in `span` and not to replace `123` which enclosed in `<span class="light">`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [reverse string trick](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) to leverage a negative look-ahead instead of a negative look-behind (that is not supported by the JavaScript regex engine):

```js
function revStr(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var rxp = new RegExp("[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?(?![^>]*>\"thgil\"=ssalc\\s+naps<)", "gm");
var str = '<div id="rep"> asd 123 asd <span class="light">123</span> asd 123 asd <span class="light">123</span> </div>';
var result = revStr(revStr(str).replace(rxp, revStr('abc')));
document.getElementById("res").value = result;
```

```html
<input id="res"/>
```

You should also use a reversed replacement string.

**EDIT**: In case you need to check if the number is not enclosed in *any* `<span>` tag with any attributes, you can use a simpler regex:

```
var rxp = new RegExp("[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?(?![^>]*>[^>]*\\bnaps<)", "gm");
```

Comment: And what if the regular expression for numbers is this: var rxp = new RegExp("(([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)|([0-9]+))", "gm");

Comment: I do not see any problems since you are only matching digits and an optional dot between the numbers: `var rxp = new RegExp("[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?(?![^>]*>\"thgil\"=ssalc\\s+naps<)", "gm");`. **EDIT**: I removed `\b` word boundary, perhaps, you also need to remove digits even in case of `xxx123`.

Comment: This is a really creative solution

Comment: @stribizhev I have a little problem that if class of span is not light, I mean if it will something that I don't know then what will be the regular expression?

Comment: @EMM: @EMM: It will be even easier: `var rxp = new RegExp("[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?(?![^>]*>[^<]*\\bnaps<)", "gm");`. [Sample code here](http://jsfiddle.net/0b4f0ja5/2/)